# The problem of finding capital letters in the text

Tags: javascript

**Expected Behavior**

I need to get capital letters only used in a text. (HTT)

**What I've tried**

First I delete the lowercase letters from string and then delete the numbers.

**Code**

```
let mesaj = "Hi TesT 124323534 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
let büyükler = mesaj.replace(/([a-z])/g, "") 
let x = büyükler.replace(/([1-9])/g, "") 
response = "HT¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

**Error**

Counts the `/` characters as capital characters.

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) can also [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) uppercase letters.

Comment: So your expected output should be `HTT` ?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. @Andreas

Comment: @eol input = "Hi TesT 124323534 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
expected output = "HTT"

Comment: @Yasin why did you say "_Counts the / characters as capital characters._" then?

Comment: for getting count of capital letters use `(mesaj.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length` and for getting Capital letters use `(mesaj.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).join('')`

Comment: @Yasin I hope this answers your question, one suggestion is to use proper headings in your question to make it more comprehensible for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let mesaj = "Hi TesT 124323534 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯";

const capString = mesaj.match(/[A-Z]+/g).join("");
const numString = mesaj.match(/[0-9]+/g).join("");
const spaceLength = mesaj.match(/ +/g).length;
console.log({
    caps : capString,
  numbers : numString,
  spaceCount : spaceLength
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do this is to replace any character that is not a uppercase character in the string:

```js
const message = "Hi TesT 124323534 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯";
const upperOnly = message.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
console.log(upperOnly);
```